# Reactjs and node js routing issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes

I'm working on a project but stuck at routing. I want to navigate from  one component to an other but i don't wan't to change url of page 
For Example:
 if it is http://localhost:3000/ so it will be this after i click on the link or button 
it will no go to http://localhost:3000/yourEnteredpath.
Hope you understand my problem if not then contact me on my mail.
And dear users make it quick as soon as possible because i don't have enough time to work on this deadline to this project is only 3 days from now.
Thankyou !! For your precious time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/MemoryRouter

Is this what you want?  As the official site says: A `<Router>` that keeps the history of your “URL” in memory (does not read or write to the address bar).

Comment: sir i'm making a post job form which you can see at this url https://www.payforworks.com/project/post-job if you fill up this form and click to next button a component load but url no changed i don't understands tutorials and documentation so can you give me a code snippet

Comment: Try using CSS to control the visibility of the component.  Do not use routing.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to conditionally render components while being on the same page. It will not change the URL and also loads the second component you want to display. For example:

```
function Greeting(props) {
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  }
  return <GuestGreeting />;
}
```

[Code sample from Official React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't want to use routing and path.
That would be the best approach in my opinion.

But  answering the question you can do that by setting a state variable to which component should be rendered.

I don't know if you are using hooks or the old set state, but either case you can have a Parent Component that renders the child Components based on the selected state.

So when you click the button you just set the state for displaying the other component.

You can have something like this inside your parent Component.

```
  switch (selected) {
    case 'componentA':
      return <ComponentA />;
    case 'componentB':
      return <ComponentB />;
    case 'componentC':
      return <ComponentC />;
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

then in the button you would setSelected('componentA') or so.

if you are using set state would be something as setState({selected: 'componentA'})